# Meta boxes not displayed, data isn't being saved

Tags: custom-field, functions

As the title says, I have a problem in functions.php (I assume it's in there) which causes custom fields to not be displayed on the new/edit post page, and when I add the meta box myself and save the data by updating the post, the data disappears.

However, if I save the data by clicking the Update button for the meta box itself (and do not click the post Update button), the data is saved and displayed properly.

I have posted the code in functions.php [here](http://pastebin.com/NXEBcf0W).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has to do with auto saving. You need to check the following before saving your fields:

```
if ( ! isset( $_POST['action'] ) || $_POST['action'] != 'editpost' || 'revision' == $post->post_type ) 
    return;
```

Comment: Thanks, you're a lifesaver! That solved the update problem. But I still don't understand why add_meta_box(); doesn't work. The custom fields are available in the dropdown Add a custom field, but they aren't displayed automatically when you add a new post and the titles of the custom fields aren't shown either.

Comment: Do you ever add the 'admin_init' function to a hook?